# How can I display all list records event it doesn't exist in database? mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of rooms

1. Deluxe
2. Standard
3. Regular

I made a display records based on what the user added per day.

If the user add a new event and use one of the room.

Example: for this day August 26,2018. one event was booked, and it will display the ff. Retrieved from database.

***Deluxe
- 1 booked***

What I want to display is this:

***Deluxe
- 1 booked***

***Standard
- none***

***Regular
- none***

I want to add all the list of rooms even some of the rooms has no value in database or
doesn't exist in database.

But how can I do it?
Please help!

My sample code:

```
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bookings");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE (start BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' OR 
    end BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end');  
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo $rows['room'];
    }
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: give us your table structure with some sample data, and your efforts

Comment: thank you for the reply. i have included my sample code. but i dont have any idea on how to do it. please help. @Joseph_J

Comment: thank you for the reply. i have included my sample code. but i dont have any idea on how to do it. please help. @MadhurBhaiya

Comment: @Pixcelleen88 what does your event table look like ? give relevant fields and sample data

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya it will display only the room that was booked. but i want to display other rooms event if doesn't have bookings yet.

Comment: @Pixcelleen88 can u give a sample table data for your `events` table ? based on the data, a query could be determined.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya these are the fields data in events table. `id`, `start`, `end`, `room`, `client`.

Comment: @Pixcelleen88 check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52023511/2469308 - let me know if it does not work - so that we can fix it accordingly

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: your posted code contains a syntax error; is that what you're really using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the OP's comments, you should get count of booked rooms per category using a [GROUP BY](https://www.guru99.com/group-by.html) clause. If there is no entry found for a particular room category, then you should let your application code handle this. Here is a sample code:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bookings");
$sql = "SELECT room, COUNT(id) as rooms_booked 
         FROM events 
         WHERE ((start BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end') OR 
                (end BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end')
               ) 
         GROUP BY room";  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

// all possible room categories
$all_room_categories = array('Deluxe', 'Standard', 'Regular');
// room categories for which there is some booking done
$booked_room_categories = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    echo $row['room'] . " - " . $row['rooms_booked'] . " booked" . "<\br>";
    $booked_room_categories[] = $row['room'];
}

// Now find all the room categories for which no booking was found
$unbooked_room_categories = array_diff($all_room_categories, $booked_room_categories);

 // Loop over unbooked rooms to print their status as well
foreach ($unbooked_room_categories as $cat)
{
    echo $cat . " - " . " none" . "<\br>";
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your inputs. I will try this out and I will give feedback once done. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Pixcelleen88 happy to help ! Welcome for further queries. If this solution works for you, kindly accept this answer and upvote too :)

Comment: What if start is before start, and is after end?

Comment: @Strawberry oops missed it. thanks for pointing out. corrected